# Simple AppleScript that causes stackoverflow—why?

Tags: applescript, stack-overflow

-- im sure this is a duplicate --

I read this in an O'reilly book (:

There was no reasoning though ):

in a simple AppleScript file:

```
script implicitRunHandlerScript
end script      

run implicitRunHandlerScript
      --    why does this lead to a stack overflow?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script you posted contains a child script, named `implicitRunHandlerScript`, and a handler, the “implicit `run` handler”.  The implicit `run` handler contains one statement:

```
run implicitRunHandlerScript
```

A child script inherits the handlers of its parent.  So your `implicitRunHandlerScript` inherits the implement `run` handler of its parent.  And that inherited implicit `run` handler calls the `run` handler of `implicitRunHandlerScript`, so it calls itself recursively.

Read [Defining Script Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/ApplescriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW2) and [Inheritance in Script Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/Conceptual/ApplescriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW5) in the *AppleScript Language Guide*.

Comment: Why would adding a beep command (or any command) to the implicitRunHandlerScript fix the recursion you describe ?

Comment: Putting a `beep` statement inside the child script (between `script implicitRunHandlerScript` and `end script` fixes the recursion, because then the child script has its own implicit `run` handler instead of inheriting the parent's.

Comment: So a script object does not have an implicit run handler until it contains an executable statement? What about the script itself (which is a script object) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have not read anything about when a script object "gains" an implicit run handler. This produces a Stack Overflow as well [Script](http://pastebin.com/YMfkCFdv) . Does an executable statement "create" the implicit run handler? +1 for pointing that out.

Comment: Read about [`run` Handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/Conceptual/ApplescriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW15) in the *AppleScript Language Guide*.

Answer (score 0):

From [AppleScript: The Definitive Guide:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102119)

> If a script object has no explicit run handler and has no executable
>   statements in its implicit run handler, telling it to run can have
>   unpredictable consequences (this fact is almost certainly a bug).